# Reuse cache dir in Phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

We have a crawler that use phantomjs. To get around memory leaks we kill and bring up a new instance of phantomjs every now and then. The problem then is that phantomjs won't use the previous cache dir that was created in earlier run, that is we see it make requests for static assets like css, javascript when it was cached in the earlier instance.

**Question: Is there a way to reuse the cache after each down/up of phantomjs? More specifically, is there a way to specify the cache directory such that phantomjs will reuse the cache that is already present?**